# Are there plans for Intel HD Graphics 4000 to support OpenGL 4.4?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, opengl

I am coding a graphics application and decided to to support Intel HD Graphics 4000, which is widely spread among notebooks. According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Seventh_generation), it currently supports OpenGL 4.0 only.

So I wonder if OpenGL 4.4 features will come available in future so that I can use them in my application.

Comment: We cannot predict the future of what Intel will or will to current products.  The simplest suggestion is to attempt to use the current drivers, the only article on the subject talking about OpenGL 4 support, is 8 months old with regards to a new driver release.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, so there are no plans about this. I think you could write that as an answer.

Comment: I didn't say they were plans.  I said we can't possibly know them.  Saying "we don't know what intel's future plans are" isn't an acceptable answer in my book

Comment: @Ramhound Alright.